# RegExp `match` issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a function, which gets all numbers from a string.Ex:

```
inputString: "Hello 2.15 digital World 5,3"
```

should return: `[2.15, 5, 3]`

My function is following:

```
function task02(inputString) {
  var reg = /^(\d+)(\.*)(\d+)$/;
  return inputString.match(reg);
}
```

Somehow it returns `null` all the time. I can't get it. RegExp was created using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `^` and `$`? Do you know what they mean? And how do you expect it to match single digits, e.g. `5` and `3`?

Comment: I thought about `(\.*)` as optional way of placing a dot. I am a completely new to Regex.

Comment: `\.*` means zero or more `.`s. But even if it's zero, the `\d+`s on each side mean it would have to be at least two digits. How about reading a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use regex `/(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?/g`

```js
function task02(inputString) {
  var reg = /(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?/g;
  return inputString.match(reg);
}

console.log(task02("Hello 2.15 digital World 5,3"));
```

Regex explanation :

```
(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BEiGUDylYYHh91L2)

Comment: @ArthurKohansky : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You must need to remove the anchors. And also the pattern for matching integer aswell as decimal numbers must be,

```
var reg = /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g;
```

`g` modifier helps to do a global match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nO8tZ1/1)